# Can I set the timezone for reports in Amazon Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have account on amazon cloud, and I am using Cloudwatch to monitor my website. But all the reports/charts in Cloudwatch are coming in as UTC time. I have to calculate time against my timezone (UTC+05:30, Indian Standard Time).

Is there any way to set the timezone for my reports?

Answer (score 17):

They've (very) recently added a drop down that allows you to set your local timezone.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The latest version of AWS DynamoDB seems to have rearranged the UI elements. Currently you can find the timezone selector when you click on `custom` period selector. There are only two options. By default, it shows the chart in "UTC". The second option is "Local timezone".

[image]